# Ecologically Correct Hugag

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures, ecology

The hugag is a fearsome critter with an inefficient-seeming anatomy:

[image]

They are quadrupedal mammals, similar to ungulates. However, their limbs are jointless, with a single long segment that connects the paws to the shoulders/hips. They also have a long upper lip, which hangs down and has very little muscle tone. They are eat leaves and live in temperate forests

Is there any niche that this hugag could fill, given the above traits?

Comment: Hmm. Poor beast. At first glance, your hugag doesn't look happy, nor viable. I wonder how this animal would ever be able to reach the water to drink without entering the water and be vulnerable for crocodiles, or unable to get out of the water. Or get upright, when it falls to one side. Also, it would not be able to descend or ascend a mountain. Its ecology better be good, to get it correct, lol !

Comment: What does "ecologically correct..." have to do with your question? What does "ecologically correct" even mean? And why wouldn't they fill the same niche every other forest-dwelling herbivore fills? Like elk and moose and giraffes.... What's the worldbuilding problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Interesting, but please focus on one niche you have in mind. This forum can't solve the plot for a poster. Voting to close for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tall Hippo**

[image]

The Hugag is a land herbivore that decided to become an aquatic animal. Its stupid legs mean it is not very good at swimming. It is much better at floating. This works fine since the Hugag eats algae.  Sometimes the Hugag also eats very small floating rocks but this on accident.

Algae lives on the water surface and is even worse at swimming than the hugug. So it can waddle along the surface and filter out the algae with its specially-designed upper lip. The algae gets swallowed and the water gets sprayed out the nostrils.

The Hugag is big enough that it has no natural predators. Young Hugags escape predators by floating downstream.

The upper lip is also used to make [very loud farting noises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhs7D8FhmIo) during the breeding season.

Comment: Absolutely,, they're badly adapted to forest life and that bill seems great for doing the sort of things that ducks do (maybe even quack, who knows).

Comment: Interesting idea, but what you describe is not a hippo. Hippos are actually very fast, very aggressive, and cannot float [https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2017/04/flight-of-the-hippopotamus/524343/].

Comment: @ETam Maybe the Hugag is also fast and aggressive? It is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

### **Unarmed and unshielded herbivore.. without knees ?**

There's an example of a "macro animal" without knees, but it died out very early.. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Hallucigenia

**Grazers without defense need some speed**

No matter how big they are, slow grazers are sitting duck. Large predators, or a pack of predators (eg wolves) love slow animals of any size. This one has no protective shield either, it's mammal, juicy prey. It can't flee, it can't turn easy, get up easy, or climb out of a river. Any slope would pose issues with the center of gravity, like horses but worse..

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=horses+stairs

**Why knees are essential to run**

Running with less impact. You need a landing with a forefoot strike, and to support that move, you need to bend your knees as well. Bending your knee when your forefoot strikes the ground helps prevent high collision and braking forces at touchdown.

**You'll need an ecologically correct environment**

Ecologically correct *environment* for this animal would be: an huge flatland with plenty of trees to graze from and a shallow lake, without any large predators on land, or in the water.

**A change I can think of..**

Of course, the straight legs are characteristic for the Hugag design, you'd want to keep them in. Now suppose the grazing of the Hugags would be beneficiary for the tree, in some way ? In that case, Hugags might survive (semi-)domesticated, helping e.g. culture forests in The Netherlands.